# Kendoui bar chart set series on click of a button

Tags: javascript, kendo-ui, kendo-chart

I am working with KendoUI bar chart. Please check this [fiddle](http://dojo.telerik.com/oTeTi). In this fiddle I am setting `series` config at the design time. I want to add `series` to the chart at run time on click of a button. How can I add `series` to kendo chart on click of a button.

**Currently `series` is assigned at the design time, i want to do the same at the run time on click of a button.**

Code:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <base href="http://demos.telerik.com/kendo-ui/bar-charts/grouped-stacked-bar">
    <style>html { font-size: 14px; font-family: Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif; }</style>
    <title></title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="//kendo.cdn.telerik.com/2016.1.112/styles/kendo.common-material.min.css" />
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="//kendo.cdn.telerik.com/2016.1.112/styles/kendo.material.min.css" />

    <script src="//kendo.cdn.telerik.com/2016.1.112/js/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <script src="//kendo.cdn.telerik.com/2016.1.112/js/kendo.all.min.js"></script>
</head>
<body>
<div id="example">
    <div class="demo-section k-content wide">
        <div id="chart"></div>
    </div>
    <script>
        function createChart() {
            $("#chart").kendoChart({
                title: {
                    text: "World population by age group and sex"
                },
                legend: {
                    visible: false
                },
                seriesDefaults: {
                    type: "column"
                },
                series: [{
                    name: "0-19",
                    stack: "Female",
                    data: [854622, 925844, 984930, 1044982, 1100941, 1139797, 1172929, 1184435, 1184654]
                }, {
                    name: "20-39",
                    stack: "Female",
                    data: [490550, 555695, 627763, 718568, 810169, 883051, 942151, 1001395, 1058439]
                }, {
                    name: "40-64",
                    stack: "Female",
                    data: [379788, 411217, 447201, 484739, 395533, 435485, 499861, 569114, 655066]
                }, {
                    name: "65-79",
                    stack: "Female",
                    data: [97894, 113287, 128808, 137459, 152171, 170262, 191015, 210767, 226956]
                }, {
                    name: "80+",
                    stack: "Female",
                    data: [16358, 18576, 24586, 30352, 36724, 42939, 46413, 54984, 66029]
                }, {
                    name: "0-19",
                    stack: "Male",
                    data: [900268, 972205, 1031421, 1094547, 1155600, 1202766, 1244870, 1263637, 1268165]
                }, {
                    name: "20-39",
                    stack: "Male",
                    data: [509133, 579487, 655494, 749511, 844496, 916479, 973694, 1036548, 1099507]
                }, {
                    name: "40-64",
                    stack: "Male",
                    data: [364179, 401396, 440844, 479798, 390590, 430666, 495030, 564169, 646563]
                }, {
                    name: "65-79",
                    stack: "Male",
                    data: [74208, 86516, 98956, 107352, 120614, 138868, 158387, 177078, 192156]
                }, {
                    name: "80+",
                    stack: "Male",
                    data: [9187, 10752, 13007, 15983, 19442, 23020, 25868, 31462, 39223]
                }],
                seriesColors: ["#cd1533", "#d43851", "#dc5c71", "#e47f8f", "#eba1ad",
                               "#009bd7", "#26aadd", "#4db9e3", "#73c8e9", "#99d7ef"],
                valueAxis: {
                    labels: {
                        template: "#= kendo.format('{0:N0}', value / 1000) # M"
                    },
                    line: {
                        visible: false
                    }
                },
                categoryAxis: {
                    categories: [1970, 1975, 1980, 1985, 1990, 1995, 2000, 2005, 2010],
                    majorGridLines: {
                        visible: false
                    }
                },
                tooltip: {
                    visible: true,
                    template: "#= series.stack #s, age #= series.name #"
                }
            });
        }

        $(document).ready(createChart);
        $(document).bind("kendo:skinChange", createChart);
    </script>
</div>


</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Your link is to a telerik page, not a fiddle. Also, please include the relevant code within the question so if the fiddle disappears over time people can still refer to your question.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you set the chart options as a global variable, you can then modify options.series and set it to your updated series data source in the button click event and call createChart() again, which will update (recreate) the chart with the updated series.

Create a global chartOptions variable:

```
var chartOptions = 
{
  title: {
  text: "World population by age group and sex"
},
legend: {
etc. etc.
```

Then create the chart with the options stored in the variable:

```
$("#chart").kendoChart(chartOptions);
```

Finally, update the options.series with the updated data and recreate the chart:

```
click: function() 
{
  chartOptions.series = updatedSeries;
  $("#chart").kendoChart(chartOptions);
}
```

I updated your Dojo and added a button that populates a new series on click.
http://dojo.telerik.com/oTeTi/3

Answer (score 7):

Ageonix gave a good answer!  If you do not want to use a global variable for the chart options, you can get the chart instance from the DOM data-attribute, add the series to the chart instance and then tell the chart to redraw:

```
var newseries = {
      name: "100+",
      stack: "Female",
      data: [654622, 625844, 784930, 844982, 900941, 39797, 72929, 118435, 118454]
};
//Get the chart
var chart = $("#chart").data("kendoChart");
//add the series
chart.options.series.push(newseries);
//refresh the chart
chart.redraw();
```

Updated **[DOJO](http://dojo.telerik.com/@ezanker/UjiHE)**

Comment: Thank you !!! I can only vote-up your answer as Ageonix also gave a right answer.

Comment: I'm also upvoting this one because it's a great alternative!

Comment: If you want to replace all old series and just show the new one, add "chart.options.series = [];" before pushing the new series.